# E: Unable to find a source package for gcc-4.8.1

Tags: osdev

I trying to follow the instruction from [this site](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingCrossCompilers) to build an i386-elf cross-compiler. At first I tried to download a cross-compiler from the mirrors the author provided. But when I noticed that those mirrors where out dated I decided to build the cross-compiler myself. When I entered this command:

```
sudo apt-get source binutils gcc-4.1
```

I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for gcc-4.1
```

I don't blame the terminal! How is it suppose to know where to find this package? Can anyone tell me how it's suppose to find the package and why it can't find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `8.` and wrote a minor version number, which is not included in package names - to get GCC from the 4.8 series you should enter:

```
sudo apt-get source binutils gcc-4.8
```

Comment: The site the OP posted said to use 4.1 https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingCrossCompilers#Get_the_source_for_binutils_and_GCC

Comment: In the answer I was referring to the question contents and title. I checked that site now. Anyway, I think it is better for the OP to not try using such an ancient version of GCC.

Comment: Now I am having trouble running this command: dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot -b > ../gcc.build 2>&1 || echo 'Build error' Probably because the version of gcc is to new!

Comment: I don't have that file.

Comment: I typed it in to my search box and it was not found.

Comment: By looking at the code I can tell that the build did not even begin. The words "build error" are from the command "dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot -b > ../gcc.build 2>&1 || echo 'Build error'".

Comment: This command has its output redirected (using `>`) to the `../gcc.build` file, as well as its error output (`2>&1`) and if the return code of dpkg-buildpackage is non-zero (using `||`) it prints "Build error". You can check the dpkg-buildpackage output by typing `less ../gcc.build`.

Comment: Is the .. realy ..? Or is it the name of a directory?

Comment: You could try before asking. `..` gives you a directory one level up

Comment: What should I look for in this file?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps source code repositories are not enabled in apt?